# LSZ Reduction Formula in Bailin & Love

Tags: renormalization, path-integral, s-matrix-theory

In [Bailin & Love](https://www.taylorfrancis.com/books/oa-mono/10.1201/9780203750100/introduction-gauge-field-theory-revised-edition-david-bailin-alexander-love) (Chapters 5-6) a formula very similar to the LSZ reduction formula is derived before any discussion of renormalization (Ch. 7).

They construct a generating functional for the S-matrix as a path integral over asymptotically free fields (those which tend to the in- and out- fields in the adiabatic limit) and split the Lagrangian into free and interacting parts (Eqs. 5.26 - 5.27), where the free Lagrangian contains the physical mass (Compare Eqs. 5.22 and 5.23 to Eqs. 5.27 and 5.38). Presumably this is the bare Lagrangian. How is this allowed? It ingores all radiative corrections to the bare mass. Is the mass shift absorbed into the interaction Lagrangian? Also, in this case, shouldn't the in- and out- fields be defined as
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow-\infty}\phi_0=\sqrt{Z_\phi}\phi_{in}
$$
and
$$
\lim_{t\rightarrow+\infty}\phi_0=\sqrt{Z_\phi}\phi_{out}
$$
in the sense of weak limits of the bare field $\phi_0$? If this is the case, the LSZ formula seems to be reproduced nicely, but it seeems strange to me in any case to introduce physical scattering processes before renormalization, and the derivations seem to play fast and loose with bare, renormalized, and physical quantities. Is there a more complete or careful derivation of the LSZ reduction formula that stays strictly within the path integral setting? I found L. Faddeev's Les Houches notes, but these have the same problem. Am I missing something?